# Move data generated by a script to Kafka topic and then to HDFS

Tags: unix, hive, apache-kafka

I have a script to get the count of messages in a specific Kafka topic and it can only be executed in the Kafka hosted server. The output of the script has to be moved to Hive/HDFS. So can I move it to Kafka topic and then move it to HDFS using HDFS Sink connector? If yes how can I move the data generated from script to Kafka topic ? Also let me know if there is a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

> how can I move the data generated from script to Kafka topic

You can pipe output of a command into a Kafka topic

```
your_script.sh | kafka-console-producer --topic foo --broker-list xx:9092
```

Or you could rewrite your script in some language that has a Kafka client. e.g. Python

---

Alternatively, you can look into setting up Apache Nifi, then run scripts there and upload results to HDFS/Hive.

---

If you want Kafka + Hive integration, Hortonworks just announced [Hive-Kafka](https://hortonworks.com/blog/introducing-hive-kafka-sql/)